# printf() surprising console output

Tags: c++, printf

I need to develop with C++ after a break of a few years. Anyway, I got problems following the tutorials I am currently reading. After writing the following code-snippet I expected to see 'Hello World' in my console, but I am only able to see 'Debug: StrangeChars'; What went wrong?

```
std::string myString("Hello World"); 
printf("* Debug: %s \n", myString);
```

Comment: This is why some people shun `printf`.

Comment: Pick any other tutorial you might find. `printf` is not the C++ way.

Comment: You're lying to your compiler: `%s` format specifier says you'll be passing `char*`.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? While this is clearly a beginner's problem, the question is perfectly precise and the answer is clear for anyone experienced. Not an intersting question for most, but well asked.

Comment: @b.buchhold I downvoted this question because of the duplicate. Very easy to find.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`printf` relies on you passing the right arguments. `%s` requires a `char *`, you passed a `std::string`.

Try (C way)

```
char myString[] = "Hello World";
printf("* Debug: %s \n", myString);
```

Or (Hybrid C/C++ way)

```
std::string myString("Hello World"); 
printf("* Debug: %s \n", myString.c_str());
```

Or the C++ way:

```
std::string myString("Hello World"); 
std::cout << "* Debug " << myString << std::endl;
```

Comment: +1 for the "C++ way". The other two options should be ignored, IMO.

Comment: @BretKuhns The question originally also had the C tag which someone removed.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
printf("* Debug %s \n", myString.c_str());
```

or better still:

```
std::cout << "* Debug " << mystring << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

The string type referenced by `printf`'s `%s%` is not the same as `std::string`.

In fact, when `printf` was specified, `std::string` did not even exist. In C++ you should use `std::cout` instead, which works as expected:

```
#include <iostream>
 [...]

std::string myString("Hello World"); 
std::cout << "* Debug: " << myString << " \n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use myString.c_str(); You're trying to output an object as a string. There's no conversion between std::string and char *

Answer (score 0):

`printf` is a C function and expects a c-string, a `char*` which is just a pointer to a place in memory where the contexts of the string reside. It assumes the string goes as far as the next `'\0'` byte and will print the contents of the memory from the address passed as pointer up to that point (the next '`\0'`).

`std::string` is a class with several members. Apart from the actual string, it stores, for example, the current size. Besides, you did not pass a pointer to the string.

If you want to use `std::string` with `printf`, you'll have to call the `c_str()` method on the string object. This method returns the content of the string object as `char*` / c-string and should always be used when using string objects with c-function that expect c-strings.

```
printf("* Debug: %s \n", myString.c_str());
```